# Большой размер картинки Base64

Tags: javascript, php, кодировка, base64

Здравствуйте. Есть код JS:

```
// Создаем новый экземпляра FileReader
var fileReader = new FileReader();

// Инициируем функцию FileReader
fileReader.onload = (function(file) {

    return function(e) {
        // Помещаем URI изображения в массив
        dataArray.push({bdID : bdID, pgID : pgID, acID : acID, name : file.name, value : this.result});
        addImage((dataArray.length-1));
    }; 

})(files[index]);

// Производим чтение картинки по URI
fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Далее я отправляю массив через AJAX в PHP файл-обработчик где через ф-ю

```
// Выделим данные
$file = $_POST['value'];
$data = explode(',', $file);

// Декодируем данные, закодированные алгоритмом MIME base64
$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$data[1]);
$decodedData = base64_decode($encodedData);

$randomName = substr_replace( sha1 ( microtime(true) * ( rand(1, 9) * 0.1 ) ) , '', 12 ).'.'.$mime;

// Создаем изображение на сервере
file_put_contents($uploaddir.$randomName, $decodedData)
```

На локалке ( OpenServer ) все работало отлично, но стоило залить все это на сервер - файлы больше 1мб загружаются по своему. Они загружаются на несколько процнтов (см. скриншот 1).

Скриншот 1. ( Слева картинка весом 0.4мб, справа 1.2мб. )

[image: скриншот 1]

```
echo ini_get('post_max_size'); // 300M
echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize'); // 300M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На хостинге присутствовала такая фишка `ModSecurity`. Выключил ее и все стало на свои места.

Answer (score 1):

Надо время для завершение загрузки учитывать тоже. Попробуйте добавить
`ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);`

Comment: 60 секунд. Вполне для одной картинки.

Comment: Стандартно обработать пробовали? 
$im = imagecreatefromstring($decodedData );
 header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($decodedData);
    imagedestroy($decodedData);

Comment: Спасибо, нашел проблему. На хостинге присутствовала такая фишка "ModSecurity". Выключил ее и все стало на свои места. Все прекрасно.